# manage.py server running twice internally

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, manage.py, django-manage.py

why while executing the command manage.py runserver in my project server runs twice.How to fix the issue.but while using --noreload this issue not arises but during api testing server doesnot respond.Shwoing file path not found.
command:-py manage.py runserver
output:-
manage.py is being executed.
Hello
manage.py is being executed.
Hello
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

command:-py manage.py runserver
output:-
manage.py is being executed.
Hello
manage.py is being executed.
Hello
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Comment: Post your `manage.py` code and format you post a bit better, it's hard to read